# Can not clear install macOS Catalina on iMac 27" late 2013

Tags: macos, catalina, imac, install

I want to sell my old iMac 27" so I secure formatted HDD with APFS and tried to install macOS (CMD + R) but  installation is aborted with an error:

**It is not possible to install mac OS on your computer.
An error occurred when configuring file attributes.
Finish the installer to restart the computer and repeat the operation.**

I reseted SMC, PRAM but it is not success.I used WiFi, I used wired connection — no success.
HDD S.M.A.R.T. is OK.
I tried installation process many times but always get this error.
What can be wrong?

[image]

Comment: @agarza - though i can't read Russian myself, the bold section would appear to already be what you're requesting.

Comment: Re-download the Installer, in case it's got corrupted somehow. Check that you can install onto another drive. I'd also use Disk Utility to verify the hard drive -- which after 9 years is likely to be on its last legs anyway.

Comment: Bold text in my message is translation of the error on screenshot)

Comment: @benwiggy HDD is ok. SMART is ok. Disk Utility verifying OK.

Comment: Is Apple boycotting Russia ?

Comment: @Ruskes Apple Online Shop and Apple Pay blocked but other services don't. 
On my another Mac I get Mac updates, I can install software, etc.

Comment: It seems HDD is dead now)
In Disk Utility capacity is 4.14 Tb, but real capacity 3 TB and Disk Is Uninitialized.
I even can not clear it now.
It worked 24/7 from January 2014.
RIP my silicon friend.

Comment: Guys tell me if I buy a new one HDD or SSD it will work fine?
Some time ago I changed HDD in my iMac 21" mid 2011 and fans goes crazy.
And I used fan utility to calm fans down.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Download macOS Catalina full installer somewhere (i.e. [App Store](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683), [Terminal](https://mrmacintosh.com/how-to-download-macos-catalina-mojave-or-high-sierra-full-installers/) or via torrent)
2. Create installation media using USB flash drive (i.e. [this guide](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372))
3. Boot from installation media
4. Launch Terminal and set computer date to approximate date of macOS Catalina you downloaded, i.e. for version 10.15.7 use command `date 093023592020` ([September 24, 2020](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/09/24/what-has-changed-in-macos-catalina-10-15-7/))
5. Exit Terminal and launch macOS installer

Comment: You don't need to do the date trick anymore if you get the installer from https://support.apple.com/HT211683 See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/309400/85275